# PHP - detect question function (who, what, when, where, why, how)

Tags: php

A detect question function I made in PHP is slightly buggy.

The function accepts a string, "$q".

Unfortunately, the function outputs "Question Detected" if the string "$q" contains "how" as part of another word. For example, the string "go to the show" returns "Question Detected". How do I fix this? I still want the function to recognize "who's/whos, "what's/whats, where's/wheres" etc...

```
function detectQuestion($q){
    $questions = array('who', 'what', 'when', 'where', 'why', 'how');
    $q = strtolower($q);
    foreach($questions as $question)
    {
        if (strpos($q, $question) !== false) {
            echo "Question Detected";
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is unclear, what are the criteria that make a sentence a question? For example, I could  assume that a sentence is a question, if it ends with a question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only match the word at the beginning of the string, not anywhere.

```
if (strpos($q, $question) === 0) {
    echo "Question detected";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Barmar, you've answered my questions before :) thanks, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I think comparing each words is better than get the string position:

```
function detectQuestion($q){
        
    $questions = array('who', 'what', 'when', 'where', 'why', 'how');
    $words = explode(' ', strtolower(trim($q)));
    
    $questionDetected = false;
    foreach($questions as $question)
    {
        /* here we put the variations of the question word */
        $similarQuestions = [$question, "$question's", $question.'s'];
        
        foreach ($words as $word) {
            /* here we check if anyword is a question word */
            if (in_array($word, $similarQuestions)) {
                $questionDetected = true;
            }
        }
    }

    echo ($questionDetected) ? 'Question detected!' : 'This is not a question';
}
```